# How do I display the setters content in PHP using overriding methods?

Tags: php, oop

this is my code:

```
<?php
    class person {
                var $name;      
                function __construct($persons_name) {
                        $this->name = $persons_name;
                }

                public function get_name() {
                        return $this->name;
                }
                protected function set_name($new_name) {
                    if ($this->name !=  "Jimmy Two Guns") {
                        $this->name = strtoupper($new_name);
                    }
                }
    }
    class employee extends person {
        protected function set_name($new_name) {
                if ($new_name ==  "Stefan TRALA") {
                    $this->name = $new_name;
                }

                else if ($new_name ==  "Johnny Fingers") {
                    person::set_name($new_name);
                }        
        }

        function __construct($employee_name) {
                $this->set_name($employee_name);
        }
    }

    $empl = new employee;
    echo $empl->set_name("Stefan TRALA");
?>
```

Im getting this warning: **Warning: Missing argument 1 for employee::__construct()** WHY ? why my echo does not work ? What did I write wrong  ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor takes one argument, so it should be:

```
$empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");
```

Then you can remove `echo $empl->set_name()` since it is already called in the constructor.

---

how to get the name?

add this function:

```
function get_name(){
  return $this->name;
}
```

then use it:

```
echo $empl->get_name();
```

Comment: but why i cannot use my set_name method ?

Comment: and also if i do a var_dump($empl) the result is null

Comment: You can if you want to , but you have it in your constructor already ` $this->set_name($employee_name);` its like calling it twice

Comment: ok, but how can i display this string "Stefan TRALA" using my methods?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a constructor function as part of your class. Constructor functions are called immediately upon class instantiation, please observe:

```
$empl = new employee;
```

This is instantiating the class, which will immediately call the following:

```
function __construct($employee_name) {
    $this->set_name($employee_name);
}
```

Obviously, we need to pass in an argument to this function initially otherwise we will get that error.

```
$empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");
```

If you need to change it later, you can with `set_name`, but it must be supplied initially.

Alternatively, you can modify the parent constructor function to expect a null but accept a proper argument:

```
function __construct($persons_name = null)
```

Comment: what do you mean by supplied initialy ??

Comment: @Blondu It must be provided as an argument to the initial instantiation as you can see in `$empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");`

Comment: ok, but how can i display this string "Stefan TRALA" using my methods?

Comment: @Blondu That is the point of a `getter` function. `function get_name(){ return $this->name; }`, then `echo $empl->get_name();` As you can see, the parent class already includes this getter method.

Answer (score 1):

Your class expects the person's name as the first argument:

```
function __construct($persons_name) {
```

Yet you call it without:

```
$empl = new employee;
```

You should either make the name optional:

```
function __construct($persons_name = '') {
```

Or pass it in on creation:

```
$empl = new employee('Joe');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor takes an argument ($employee_name)

So you need to instantiate your employee using
    $empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");

But also your echo statement is calling a function with no return value. You need to use the get_name function, not set_name, to return the value.

```
echo $empl->get_name();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is not about setters, you are not specifying the parameter at the constructor.

Your code:

```
$empl = new employee;
echo $empl->set_name("Stefan TRALA");
```

Is the same as:

```
$empl = new employee();
echo $empl->set_name("Stefan TRALA");
```

The fix:

```
$empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");
// this works, but, no longer necesarilly
//echo $empl->set_name("Stefan TRALA");
```

Remember, every time you use the "new" keyword, you are executing a constructor.

And, constructors are written like this:

```
$empl = new employee("Stefan TRALA");
```

But, should be read (not written) as this:

```
$empl = new employee; $empl->__construct("Stefan TRALA");
```

The error is not at the "setter".

Cheers.